# How to display google calendar "reminders" on macOS calendar app?

Tags: macos, calendar, google-calendar

So google recently [implemented](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2016/04/reminders-come-to-google-calendar-on-the-web.html) *reminders* on both their web application and their mobile applications. This is a nifty little feature that instead of creating *events* on your calendar it creates these entries which, if not marked as done, will stay there until you complete them.

When you add reminders a new "Reminders" calendar now appear under "My Calendars" list, however, I noticed that the macOS calendar app does not display this calendar, hence, no reminders there.

Is there some way to also see reminders within the calendar app on macOS?

Comment: Don't think so. Try looking at the reminders app. Mac usually keeps calendars separate from Reminders.

Comment: @bret7600 the reminders in google calendar ARE events and appear as another calendar in the calendar list.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @dewald.c.els Nop, I just stopped using calendar native apps and just go through the website, sadly that's the only way it works since reminders are not actually part of the standard iCal thing but a proprietary feature of google it seems, as much as the "goals" which I keep using.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Fluid to make a stand alone Google Calendar app using https://calendar.google.com as URL.

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question?  See [answer] for important info in order to avoid downvotes.